# Answers without sources

Tags: support, answers

In my own personal research, I came across information that was used as an answer for a question on the main site. The answer had no links or citing of the source material. It even looks as the information was copy/pasted into the answer box.

How does one go about making sure that the answer is linked to the source material?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know where it was copied from, then flag with "it needs moderator information" and explain it in the text box. Something like

> This answer is copied from [link].

Otherwise, like the moderator curiousdannii indicates in the comments

> (...) flag as Very Low Quality.

Comment: If you're certain it was plagiarised, do this. Otherwise flag as Very Low Quality.